Different solution using scikit-learn and cvxpy
I am trying to code a logistic regression model using the CVXPY library. The code I have written so far "works" in the sense that it can be executed, it does not yield any error message and provides a solution. However, this solution does not match the solution provided by the scikit-learn implementation of logistic regression.
I know scikit-learns implementation includes an L2 penalty by default, and in the code example below you will see that I changed this to None. Also I removed the intercept from the sklearn model. But still the solutions do not match:
import cvxpy as cp
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

X, y = make_classification(n_features=10, random_state=42)

sk = LogisticRegression(penalty=None, fit_intercept=False)
sk.fit(X, y)
print(sk.coef_)

This produces the output:
[[-13.46939518  -7.09935934  19.41989522 -10.36990818   3.76335965
2.84616038   3.32474461  -2.84162961   3.13246888   1.08887971]]

Now, the cvxpy implementation:
beta = cp.Variable(X.shape[1])
log_likelihood = cp.sum(cp.multiply(y, X @ beta) - cp.logistic(X @ beta))
problem = cp.Problem(cp.Maximize(log_likelihood/X.shape[0]))
problem.solve()
beta = beta.value
print(beta)

produces the solution:
[-31.38130594 -10.72178524  44.07489985 -34.06127916   8.01950276
   5.96941765   9.6143194   -7.88785049  12.96349703  -0.13264449]


It would be more helpful to look at the testing or validation results of both the outcomes. The weight assignment may differ individually however it is possible that the optimization goal (i.e., in this case classification with minimal error) is reached equally well by both. The endgame of Classification is to establish a decision boundary, and hence two seemingly different may deliver same results as well.

Thank you for your comment, but I think that in the case of logistic regression, the classifier is built by minimizing a convex function. The minimization of a convex low dimensional regression problem as is this logistic regression exapmle should yield only one optimal solution within a certain threshold. However scikit-learn and cvxpy provide two very different solutions to the same problem.

Do you have a reference for the log-likelihood formula you're using?

@ÁlvaroMéndezCivieta actually true I completely overlooked that part. However, did you look at the vladiation and testing results so far? What do they tell?

@BenReiniger you can find the log-likelihood formulation on a post from CVXPY but I also checked it myself by deriving it from the likelihood formula. I am 100% sure that the loglikelihood function I include in the code is correct.  the validation and test results show that the scikit-learn solution seem to provide smaller errors (as meassured by the accuracy of the model)

Cross-posted at https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/652935/232706

OK, I've identified two other issues, fixing those results in essentially the same coefficients, so I'm quite confident that the log-loss given is correct.  See the CV post.
